# Null Pointer Exception when calling java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit() from OS X Applet

Tags: java, macos, applet, awt

I'm getting the following NPE when trying to view a Java applet on OS X 10.7.5:

```
[2014-04-07T11:39:22.035] [thread applet-com.OTHERCOMPANY.wave.applets.PRODUCT.PRODUCT.class-2] com.COMPANY.nm.logging.LogMaster.auditLoggingMessage AUDIT: HEMXL0001A=Audit logging is enabled.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.COMPANY.XYZ.applets.PRODUCT.ui.table.TableMouseListener.<init>(TableMouseListener.java:71)
    at com.COMPANY.XYZ.applets.PRODUCT.PRODUCTTable.<init>(PRODUCTTable.java:315)
```

I do not have the source but assume to have found TableMouseListener.java:71 using javap:

```
  public com.COMPANY.XYZ.applets.PRODUCT.ui.table.TableMouseListener(com.COMPANY.XYZ.applets.PRODUCT.PRODUCTContext, javax.swing.JTable);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=5, locals=4, args_size=3
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method com/OTHERCOMPANY/wave/uicomponents/PopupListener."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: aconst_null   
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field firstClickEvent:Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;
         9: aload_0       
        10: aload_1       
        11: putfield      #3                  // Field context:Lcom/COMPANY/XYZ/applets/PRODUCT/PRODUCTContext;
        14: aload_0       
        15: aload_2       
        16: putfield      #4                  // Field table:Ljavax/swing/JTable;
THIS  --->    
        19: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/awt/Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit:()Ljava/awt/Toolkit;
        22: ldc           #6                  // String awt.multiClickInterval
        24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/awt/Toolkit.getDesktopProperty:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        27: checkcast     #8                  // class java/lang/Integer
        30: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
        33: istore_3      
        34: aload_0       
THIS  --->    
        35: new           #10                 // class javax/swing/Timer
        38: dup           
        39: iload_3       
        40: aload_0       
        41: invokespecial #11                 // Method javax/swing/Timer."<init>":(ILjava/awt/event/ActionListener;)V
        44: putfield      #12                 // Field clickTimer:Ljavax/swing/Timer;
        47: return        
      LineNumberTable:
        line 65: 0
        line 62: 4
        line 66: 9
        line 67: 14
        line 71: 19
        line 72: 34
        line 73: 47
```

Any good ideas what might cause this and what could be a workaround? I'm not exactly clear on what this toolkit does but it seems to provide an interface to the graphics system which might be restricted from the applet sandbox?

Some stuff I have investigated:

- this did not happen with an older version of the applet that did not call getDefaultToolkit()
- this seems only to happen on OS X, Windows and Linux are fine
- I have tried the medium applet security setting, deleting the Java cache and some other voodoo to no avail
- Generally calling this method outside of an applet works fine, see below.

> ```
> $ cat gettk.java 
> import java.awt.*;
>
> public class gettk {
>     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
>         System.out.println("tk = " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit());
>     }
> }
> $ java gettk
> tk = sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit@32d16dc8
> ```

Update I: as suggested by a comment, here's a nicer decompile. Line 71 is:

```
 int multiClickInterval = ((Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval")).intValue();
```

Turns out the problem might very well be the usage of awt.multiClickInterval. I'll check if I can shoehorn this in from `<embed>` properties.

Update II:

Yes the missing `awt.multiClickInterval` is the issue:

```
rc@ds9000:~ $ cat gettk.java 
import java.awt.*;

public class gettk {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("tk = " + Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit());
    int multiClickInterval = ((Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval")).intValue();
    System.out.println(multiClickInterval);
    }
}
rc@ds9000:~ $ java gettk
tk = sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit@15e6e48b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gettk.main(gettk.java:6)
```

Unfortunately I seem to be unable to pass it as system property:

```
rc@ds9000:~ $ java -Dawt.multiClickInterval=200 gettk 
tk = sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit@15e6e48b
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gettk.main(gettk.java:6)
```

Wierdly enough there is a note on how this was fixed in [OS X 10.5 here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Java/JavaLeopardUpdate4RN/ResolvedIssues/ResolvedIssues.html) (by Apple?), but also [multiple instances of WONTFIX for Java 7 and 8 in the upstream JDK Jira here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7124404?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab).

Comment: There are several java decompilers out there. They aren't perfect, but at least they make *human readable* code. Please use one and edit your question. Try http://jd.benow.ca

Comment: Thanks, updated. the awt.multiClickInterval query might be the problem

Comment: Yes, I think so too. Try running the program on the command line with `-Dawt.multiClickInterval=200` (or whatever your OS multi click interval is)

Comment: Seems really to be the issue. Unfortunately this property doesn't seem to be settable from -D system properties, see pastes above. Looks like I need to find another way to get this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha. I found a fix for you. It requires some hacks though.

```
public class HackApplet extends WhateverRandomAppletClassItWas {
    public void init(){
         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval", 200);
         super.init();
    }
}
```

Then just get rid of the actual applet's signature (if any), add you custom applet in, manually sign (otherwise I'm sure `setDesktopProperty` isn't going to work), and it should work.

Comment: That's a cool idea. Unfortunately this whole thing is a commercial package which includes the application server, the generated page with the applet code and the applet being signed by $BIGCOMPANY, but as a temporary workaround for just the OS X users this should work. Thanks!